# Hibernate does not drop H2 Database when FK exist

Tags: hibernate, h2, ddl

H2Dialect.dropConstraints has a comment

```
// We don't need to drop constraints before dropping tables, that just leads to error
// messages about missing tables when we don't have a schema in the database
```

But this seems to be wrong, when my next Unittest-Class starts with custom properties set

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = {
        "aaa=bbb"})
```

a new context is created and Hibernate tries to drop the schema to create it newly. Which leads to constraint exceptions:

```
Cannot drop "XXX" because "FK_XXX, FK_XXX, FK_XXX, FK_XXX" depends on it; SQL statement:

    drop table xxx if exists [90107-200]
```

Why won't the H2Dialect drop constraints correctly?

Answer (score 0):

H2 1.4.200 is more compliant with the SQL Standard than earlier versions and Hibernate does not really support changes in that version yet, but there is a pull request with a fix for `H2Dialect` (I didn't test it): [#3093](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/3093). You can try to use an own dialect with the similar changes.

See also [HHH-13711](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/HHH/issues/HHH-13711).